# send Data to controller from Jquery. MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

my jquery script code part  , the script is working fine and set data array/object in dataBLL..

```
var dataBLL = [];
$('#mytable tr').each(function (i) {

dataBLL.push({

id: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
ctype: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
cpath: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
ckey: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
ckey: $(this).find('td:eq(4) input:frist').val(),

});
  $.ajax ({
             url:"User/BllBtn",
             type:"POST",
             data:"dataBll="JSON.stringify(dataBLL);
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (e) {

                alert("sucess");
            }})
```

but i am not able to send this object/Array to my controller to use it's data and iterate through each row entry .

My controller signature

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResutl BllBtn(List<string> dataBll)
{

}
```

Please guide how to get this object as list so I can loop into in simplest way.

Comment: what to do then .. any code change requeied @Div

Comment: getting null in  List<string> dataBll :( @Div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a syntax error (which your browser console will have told you), and also you're producing invalid JSON.

`data: { "dataBll": dataBLL }`

should work I think. Or

`data: JSON.stringify({ "dataBll": dataBLL })`

at worst. Also set

`contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`

as another option in the ajax call.

The next problem is you are trying to accept `List<string>` into your method, but `dataBll` is a complex object with the following properties:

`id, ctype, cpath, ckey, ckey`

Firstly, you can't define ckey twice in the same object, and secondly your JSON object is incompatible with the type in the C# method. You need to define a class, e.g.

```
public class myNewType
{
  public string id {get; set; }
  public string ctype {get; set; }
  public string cpath {get; set; }
  public string ckey {get; set; }
}
```

and then accept `List<myNewType>` as the parameter to the method:

```
public ActionResult BllBtn(List<myNewType> dataBll)
```

Comment: please help how to produce valid JSON ..any code exaple! @ADyson

Comment: no i am not getting any data in my action , only count 1 at index[0] with key names only  nothing else :(

Comment: any other method you know to if it is working i will follow that @ADyson

Comment: Its `data: JSON.stringify({ "dataBll": dataBLL }),` and you also need to set `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',`

Comment: Done it , but again how to get the value in controller  ActionResult BllBtn  :( @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to change the method to `public ActionResult BllBtn(List<myNewType> dataBll)` and create the view model as per this answer (and note that you need to rename one of the `ckey` properties in you javascript object other wise it will result in an exception)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I hadn't noticed the missing contentType setting. Have updated the answer for completeness.